# Parsing the columns and data of a record from an xml table with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

I have an xml object that has been returned via an ajax call that contains 1 record, 33 columns (there will only ever be 1 record or non) and looks like this

```
    xml "<Table>
    <Supplier>false</Supplier>
    <Address>true</Address>
    <ProductInformation>true</ProductInformation>
    <ProductDetail>true</ProductDetail>
    <BusinessRef>true</BusinessRef>
    <RequiredLiveDate>true</RequiredLiveDate>
    <ActualLiveDateCheck>true</ActualLiveDateCheck>
    <ABEndCheck>true</ABEndCheck>
    <FloorRoomRackSpace>true</FloorRoomRackSpace>
    <PremisesNameNum>true</PremisesNameNum>
    <PremisesExists>true</PremisesExists>
    <IsSiteSecure>true</IsSiteSecure>
    <CheckTechPres>true</CheckTechPres>
    <CheckSepAndResil>true</CheckSepAndResil>
    <SuppConfSepAndRes>true</SuppConfSepAndRes>
    <DelDateContingency>true</DelDateContingency>
    <AwareOfTimeIssues>true</AwareOfTimeIssues>
    <VisitorsNames>true</VisitorsNames>
    <VisitorsTelNum>true</VisitorsTelNum>
    <VisitorsCompanyName>true</VisitorsCompanyName>
    <VisitorsNationality>true</VisitorsNationality>
    <VisitorsClearanceLvl>true</VisitorsClearanceLvl>
    <VisitorsCarReg>true</VisitorsCarReg>
    <SiteVisitSponserNme>true</SiteVisitSponserNme>
    <SiteVisitArrvalDate>true</SiteVisitArrvalDate>
    <SiteVisitTimeSart>true</SiteVisitTimeSart>
    <SiteVisitTimeEnd>true</SiteVisitTimeEnd>
    <WhichAreaToBeVisited>true</WhichAreaToBeVisited>
    <WhoIsToMeetVisitor>true</WhoIsToMeetVisitor>
    <FSSiteName>NA</FSSiteName>
    <WorkType>Cabling</WorkType>
    <VisitorContact>Alan Legg</VisitorContact>
    <SiteLocation>Tech Hall 1</SiteLocation>
</Table>"   String
```

and here is the code that pulls the data in:

```
        function getExistingCheckList() {
        var PWNum = 'PW11896';
        var testddl = $("#testddl");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Circuits_OrderManagementTracker.aspx/getAnyChecklistRecords",
            data: "{'PWNum': '" + PWNum + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
                var xml = $(xmlDoc);
                var CheckListsReturned = xml.find("Table");

              $.each(CheckListsReturned, function (index, CheckListsReturned) {
                    ColumnName = $(this).find("title").????()
                    columnsData = $(this).find("title").????()
                    testddl.append('<option>' + ColumnName + '</option>');
                    testddl2.append('<option>' + columnsData + '</option>');
                });
            },
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
    }
```

I wish to iterate through the xml pulling out the column name and the the columns value for all 33 columns and populate the 2 dropdowns, but im struggling with the syntax, could you help me please?

Comment: If it's XML, why do you have `dataType: "json"` in theAJAX call?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the actual XML tags.

Comment: Hi Barmar i tired to add the tags but the page processed it and it only seemed to show the processed xml. ill add it but am unsure how to get it to show as it in its raw state.

Comment: If you use the `{}` tool to mark code, it won't process it.

Comment: Thanks Barmar i appreciate your advise, as for the json, well its works and im so new to coding and it did not seem to error i left it (basically i scraped the code from and example to try to learn from a working example that all), i can change that later...

Comment: I guess you're wrapping the XML in JSON. Not really necessary, but OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checkListsReturned = xml.find("Table").children();
checkListsReturned.each(function() {
    var columnName = $(this)[0].tagName;
    var columnData = $(this).text();
    testddl.append('<option>' + ColumnName + '</option>');
    testddl2.append('<option>' + columnData + '</option>');
});
```